# How to display dynamic json data in angular?

Tags: json, angular

I am a beginner in angular. My question is - Based on the excel file which user uploads, api returns some data in JSON format. So the column headers and data are dynamic. I want to display the json data in HTML table.

I want to know how should my json look like and its respective TS and HTML code.

User upload an excel file like this
[file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otFTP.png)

My output should look like this :
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAVoB.png)
First column and row is dynamic.

Comment: This seems like a full-stack question. When I google JavaScript libraries that read Excel, I see dollar signs. Generating JSON in JavaScript is straightforward (JSON.stringify a JS object) but I'd instead use Newtonsoft to generate the JSON server side because I'd also use a free .NET library to read the Excel (there are many). I'm commenting and not answering as I don't know if this is feasible for you. Plus, my answer would be HUGE as it would include posting a blob with rxjs, subscribing and parsing the JSON response into a table -- I don't even know what server-side tech you are using.

Comment: I don’t have to read excel. The user uploads a file and I send that file to the back end through an endpoint, then the back end sends json data through another endpoint which I want to display in a table. My confusion here is when I don’t know column headers , what should I write in interface? Please check image 2, to show that image in a table how should my json look like? Also, the first row and column (headers) change every time depending on the file they upload.

Comment: OK. Your image links aren't working for me. They would probably have helped me to be more on the nose with my comment.

Answer (score 1):

As you are new to Angular, I will show you one of the procedure you can use

Angular part:

Every time the server sends data, you can get your data by HTTP methods or web-socket by "service" from angular.

Service:

in services, you can import HTTP to get data and after you get data you can emit it by using "behavior-subject" to any component you want which contains your tables and save data values there. (behavior-subject is from rxjs library).

Component:

Now your component in angular has the json data every time and you can analyze
your JSON file, based on your JSON shape you can use *ngfor in the HTML part of the component table and it will change the table online.